# Getting ES2015 Proxy-like behavior in Safari

Tags: javascript, proxy, safari, ecmascript-6

I just discovered that current iOS doesn't support ES2015 and `Proxy` yet. I have a very small `Proxy` object in my code, which I'm using to allow a function to be called upon access to `myobject.non_formally_defined_property`, where I have no explicit property or property getter defined for the property in question.

**How I can implement ES2015-compatible Proxy-like behavior?** I want to continue to keep things the way they are. (A refactor would probably be ~20 lines of code, but the result would be a *mess* - I'm using this to implement initialization-time values for running configuration/state.)

After learning about `defineProperty` I tried wiring that up to use the same function for all property accesses, but I'm very perplexed by the specific way it didn't work.

Specifically, I did this:

```js
'use strict';

var arr = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}

var obj = {};

for (var item in arr) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, item, {
    get: function (value) {
      var local1 = item;
      var local2 = (' ' + item).slice(1);
      console.log('get: item=' + item + '  local1=' + local1 + "  local2=" + local2);
    },
  });
}

obj.one;
```

```html
<pre id=log></pre>
```

If you click <kbd>Run Code</kbd>, you'll see that `console.log()` prints `item=three  local1=three local2=three`.

This is very confusing to me because

- I don't *think* I'm overwriting the setter - I'm running `defineProperty` on the same object, yes, but on a different `item` each time - so the closures should be different, right? - but I'm seeing *three*.

  The only way I can reason about that is that

  - That was the final loop value when the last closure (which overwrite the others?) was created, or
  - `item`, `local1` and `local2` are somehow being fished out of the parent lexical scope, and of course they're all `three` from the final loop iteration. *This doesn't make any sense though, because...*
- ...`var` creates locally-scoped variables which are independent. To ensure the `local*` variables were unique, I  `local1` is a simple `=` association, and `local2` is a "deep copy" hack I grabbed [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712808/how-to-force-javascript-to-deep-copy-a-string) just in case the copied string was linked by reference to the original.

So by every metric I can think of, the closures should be different, and I should be seeing the right variable show up. I'm very curious to understand why my approach doesn't work, but I'm especially interested to know how I can get getters/setters working!

Note that I want both get and set functionality, but I've only discussed getting here for simplicity.

**I do not want to use any libraries.** In my case this is because the JavaScript code is going into an HTML file I am emailing someone, I only want to email one file, and some pregenerated tables elsewhere in the HTML are already using 300KB+.

Comment: Is your question why your `defineProperty` code doesn't work?

Comment: ...And now I get what you mean, thanks for the persistent clarification :) I updated the title (it previously said "ES2015/Safari").

Comment: The TL;DR of my question is "how do I get Proxy-like behavior? I tried this approach and it didn't work. Is my approach on the right track, or do I need to try something else?"

Comment: Ack, marking the duplicate deleted my previous comment which had a lot more than just the duplicate link in it. *sigh* Anyway, marked as duplicate because if you just need the property to behave correctly, yes, you're on the right track with `defineProperty` and it's just a closures-in-loops error. If Safari handles `let` correctly, just change the `var` in `for (var item in arr) {` to `let`. If it doesn't, the linked question's answers provide solutions that work even in ES5.

Comment: The answer to the general case "How do I get Proxy-like behavior" is: Other than getters/setters, you can't; Proxy isn't polyfillable. But what you've done is not only a solid way to work around not having Proxy in Safari, it's probably a better solution than Proxy was anyway. :-) Proxy is very expensive.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I did actually see the other comment before it got chewed, FWIW. iOS [doesn't support `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility), so I went with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19324832/3229684) instead.

Comment: Looks like MDN's out of date, I got curious a while ago and tested it in iOS Safari on my iPad (iOS 10.3.3): http://jsfiddle.net/Lt4L2kr4/ That shows 012, whereas it would show 333 if `let` weren't handled correctly in that loop. (For example, IE11 shows 333 because although it supports a version of `let`, it doesn't support ES2015's semantics for it.)