# javascript - coping object element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to copy the name from one object to another as below:

```
console.log(this.source.name)
```

//gives `"mike"`

```
mounted: function() {
   this.client.name = Object.assign({}, this.source.name)
}
```

then

```
console.log(this.client.name)
```

//gives object with `1: m, 2: i, 3: k, 4:e`

What I'm doing wrong? How should I correct my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force JavaScript to deep copy a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712808/how-to-force-javascript-to-deep-copy-a-string)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca maybe but I don't understand this example

Comment: `Object.assign({}, 'mike')` – how would you expect the resulting object to have an attribute `mike` with a value?

Comment: Man, why not just `this.client.name = this.source.name` lol

Comment: @Dencio you're not wrong

Comment: @Dencio okay guys, I'm js newbie, I wanted just to copy element of the object, when I copied objects in the past, I got wrong results so I started to using Object.assign function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` takes two object params, but you're passing a `string` to second param. So, if you want to assign string value simply do `this.client.name = this.source.name`.

If you want to copy object value, use `Object.assign` and store an object in `this.source.name` as `this.source.name={"key":"value"};`.

Comment: this is the right answer, Object assign could be used but not in this case. Thanks for valuable advice

Comment: @gileneusz Just console and then check the documentation when such thing happens.

Comment: This has the downside of creating a reference. Change `this.source.name` and `this.client.name` will also change. That may be wanted or not, but it should be noted.

Comment: @connexo `this.client.name = this.source.name` refers to assigning string value, not the object.

Comment: @connexo this is why I tried to use Object.assign function. I wanted to avoid this.source.name changes to affect this.client.name later on

Comment: `name` might be as well be an `object` looking similar to this `{ firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Molyneux", middleName: "" }`

Comment: @connexo it depends on what exactly you want to perform.

Comment: I'm not saying you're doing anything wrong, I'm just pointing out potential issues.

Comment: Oh! okay. Yeah, that's true. directly assigning object will lead to the issue you mentioned.

Comment: thank you guys for a valuable discussion. I learned a lot from it, and you are both right :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following adjustment:

```
this.client = Object.assign({}, this.client,  {name: this.source.name})
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, this is also correct and could be used on arrays inside object element (?)

Comment: Doesn't matter what type of data `this.source.name` holds.

Comment: so this way is more universal. I will keep @AmanshuKataria answer as a correct because it's more simpler and easy to use

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax for this

```js
const b = {iam b}
const a = {...b}
console.log(a) // {iam b}
```

Comment: As you can see, you must have missed something.